# How do I install QtTest for the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, testing, quality

When I select "Build -> Ubuntu Touch -> Create Application Package" in the Ubuntu SDK, the build fails with the error "FAIL!  : qmltestrunner::tst_hellocomponent::compile() module "QtTest" is not installed".  How can I install the QtTest module so that I can build a package?

Comment: what about using `qmake` and `make` before running it with ./QtTest

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me to do.

Comment: Have you tried building it outside of the IDE? I assume you're using QtCreator?

Comment: No, I have no idea how I would do that.

Comment: Maybe you need to put `QT += testlib` into your .pro file

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package [qtdeclarative5-test-plugin [image: Install qtdeclarative5-test-plugin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtdeclarative5-test-plugin)